# The PDF generated by the journal LaTeX template downloaded through IEEE Template Selector does not meet the requirements of the journal

Tags: templates, format, ieee

such as IEEE Transactions on Affective Computing format is shown below,
[image]
The PDF generated by the template obtained through [IEEE Template Selector](https://template-selector.ieee.org/secure/templateSelector/publicationType) is not in this format. How do I get the right template? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think that what you submit is used as is?  It is more than likely that the journal typesets in a way that is different from what you submit.

Comment: "Does not meet the requirements of the journal" is different than "looks different than what I get".  Their requirements are that you use their template.  Unless they have a requirement that your pdf must match their output, then you're fine.  (And as deleif notes, they will likely use a different template for the final product.  But you using their template makes it easier for them to use their other template later on.)

Comment: In the past, as a reviewer, I reviewed the manuscript format as shown in the picture. According to your explanation @daleif@Teepeemm, are manuscripts submitted to the IEEE Transactions on Affective Computing further typesetted by the journal and then assigned to reviewers?

Comment: @qianfan1996 none of us work for the journal so we have no idea. We just know that it is common for journal submit templates to have a different look than the end result (for example if the journal are using commercial fonts)

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind and helpful answers!